# Having trouble starting Tails from DVD

Tags: tails, help

Trying to get started with Tails. downloaded .iso, verified key sig, burned dvd, (verified)

but can't figure out how to start Tails or the Tails Installer, as I cannot find that app.

DVD (and .iso image) have only the following four folders:
EFI, isolinux, live, utils.

instructions say: "Start Tails from another media than the device, USB stick or SD card, onto which you want to install Tails."
 how? thanks.
i'm on a mac.

https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tails?page=4&sort=newest&pagesize=15

Answer (score 1):

Typically how you do this is to boot your computer by setting the DVD-rom as boot device. You can check the boot device order in bios settings.

Or there is typically a hot-key you can press to select boot device during start-up.
After that when Tails has loaded you can find the 'installer' application in the application menu inside Tails OS itself, from there you can then install the running Tails on to a USB stick for example.

Comment: thank you for this advice. it did help, i was able to get the Tails running from the DVD and then find installer and run to install on USB. installation seemed to go fine, BUT when I try to reboot from USB it gets stuck as it loads. reinstalled but same problem.

Comment: also, is it safe to run tails from the DVD? i'd prefer the ease of the USB but if need be i can just use the DVD>..

Comment: It did the same for me (it seems like it stopped loading and asked for login, but after a while it resumes loading and works fine. Please try again and give it some minutes. If it does not help then let us know exactly where it gets stuck.

Comment: Its safe to run from DVD. So you can use that if you want to. The usb is better if you need / want a persistent place to store data encrypted to access with tails. ( bookmarks, settings, files and so on.).

Comment: thank you. yes, i would like the persistent storage, but may just have to by another laptop or something. i suspect it's a mac compatibility issue.